# Best Approach for maintaining configuration safely

Tags: ios, plist

## Overview:

I have an **iOS** project which contains the server configurations in a **Plist**. I have different plists for different targets (Dev / Stage etc)

## Problem:

This plist gets copied to the main bundle, so I feel it is not so safe as one can get it from the `ipa` file. I would like it not be accessible.

## Question:

- What would be the best approach to maintain server configurations for different targets ?
- Can plists be used if so how to make it not accessible via the `ipa` file and yet be readable through code ?
- Is there a better approach to solve this problem ?

Comment: "I would like it not be accessible." This isn't possible. You'll need to make some choices about how hard you want to make it to access vs how much effort you're willing to spend on it. With significant effort, you should expect to stop a skilled attacker for a few hours. With modest effort, you should expect to stop an automated script. (With massive effort and expense, you may be able to stop a skilled and motivated attacker for a few weeks or maybe months.) What's your budget for protecting this information?

Comment: @RobNapier My Budget is a few hundred dollars and about 1 week coding time. It is a swift app

Comment: It is a swift app

Comment: Take a look here for the slides/notes from my latest talk and some tools. It's a very complex topic. https://github.com/rnapier/secrets

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look at it and let you know if I have some doubts.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using plists by hardcoding the config. This way it is compiled into the app and not easily accessible via the ipa file. It's not entirely secure, but less accessible than a plist.

Create a file `MyConfigDev.swift`

```
// this file is added to the Dev target
class Config {
    private init() {}
    static let shared = Config()
    let myParam = "valueForDev"
}
```

And another file `MyConfigStaging.swift`

```
// this file is added to the Staging target
class Config {
    private init() {}
    static let shared = Config()
    let myParam = "valueForStaging"
}
```

If you build the Dev target the file `MyConfigDev.swift`is used, if you build the Staging target the file `MyConfigStaging.swift`is used.

In your code you can access the config:

```
let p = Config.shared.myParam
```

To get access to your configuration hackers will now need to decompile your ipa.

Comment: Decompiling the IPA is not necessary. These strings are easily extracted by running `strings` on the app binary. It's slightly harder than reading a plist, but not much. (It may be enough to ease the OP's mind, however, so it's a step forward.)

Comment: Thanks Peter, that is definitely better than the plist option and may be use active compilation flags (build settings) to differentiate the different environments.

Comment: @RobNapier is there a better approach than using strings ?

Comment: This is a swift app just to add some context to the problem